# Objective-c, Is there any way fetch video thumbnail from URL instead using MPMoviePlayerController and AVAssetImageGenerator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, video-thumbnails

I want to fetch video thumbnail from URL instead using `MPMoviePlayerController` and `AVAssetImageGenerator`. Because these have some issue. Issue I have already asked,

**1st one is :** [AVAssetImageGenerator not working properly, I am unable to fetch thumbnail of video from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423062/avassetimagegenerator-not-working-properly-i-am-unable-to-fetch-thumbnail-of-vi)

**and 2nd is :** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32431311/mpmovieplayercontroller-not-fetching-thumbnail-of-video-from-url-properly

I have no idea how to do it. Any suggestion will be great. Thank in advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to put into comment below your URL and `self.imageView.image = FrameImage;`

Anyway.

```
NSString *str=@"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t50.2886-16/11719145_918467924880620_816495633_n.mp4";
NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:str];

AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform=TRUE;
NSError *error = NULL;
CMTime thumbTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0,30);

CGImageRef refImg = [generator copyCGImageAtTime:thumbTime actualTime:NULL error:&error];
if(error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
UIImage *FrameImage= [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:refImg];
[self.imageView setImage:FrameImage];
```

Comment: @ Moldaone , Shall you please read what I am asking and what you are telling me. please Read my question+ my very  latest comment carefully then give answers. Thanks ..

Comment: @Monusingh Now the question: why you don't want to use `AVFoundation` ? Which issues you have with `AV`?

Comment: @ Moldanone, I have already defined in my question , see on the top (in this page) in my question , I have define 2 issues. Thanks

Comment: @Monusingh Did you try the code? Because everything is working fine and code below fetch thumbnail without issues.

Comment: @ Moldanone, I have tried my own code, Let me try your code if works fine then +1 from my side. Thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"[video URL]"] options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator *generateImg = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
NSError *error = NULL;
CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 65);
CGImageRef refImg = [generateImg copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&error];
NSLog(@"error==%@, Refimage==%@", error, refImg);

UIImage *FrameImage= [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:refImg];
```

Comment: @ Moldaone , I am asking fetch video thumbnail from URL instead using **MPMoviePlayerController and AVAssetImageGenerator**. Please give another solution. Thanks